# trying to understand offsetExists function in Zend/Registry.php

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
 public function offsetExists($index)
    {
        return array_key_exists($index, $this);
    }
```

This is taken from Zend/Registry.php, my question is:
`$this` is the current object, right? but here it seems also an array? so what does  `$this` actually mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice that [`Zend_Registry`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Registry.php) extends `ArrayObject`. This allows it to be used *like* an array.

Further reading - http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

The reason `Zend_Registry` overrides `ArrayObject::offsetExists()` is due to this bug - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40442